# Интересная задача на python

Tags: python

Используя монеты достоинством в 2, 3 и 5 копеек представить сумму 99 копеек, затратив ровно 22 монеты.

Comment: А что тут собственно интересного-то?

Comment: А есть ли общее условие для этой задачи?

Answer (score 9):

очень интересная задача, особенно на питоне

```
2x + 3y + 5z = 99
x + y + z = 22
```

откуда

```
y + 3z = 55

z = 18 + (1-y) / 3
```

первое решение при `y = 1`:

```
y = 1 z = 18 x = 3
```

Так, решение есть, а питона пока все еще нет :(((

Ну ладно, попробуем дальше

очевидно, что `y = 3n + 1`, где `n = [0..7]`

тогда:

```
z = 18 - n
y = 3n + 1
x = 3 - 2n
n = [0..7]
```

И опять нет питона :(

Идем дальше:

`x = 3 - 2n` дает ограничение на `n = [0..1]`

Что даёт нам указанное выше решение:

```
x = 3 y = 1 z = 18
```

и еще одно

```
x = 1 y = 4 z = 17
```

Вот теперь мы можем написать программу на Питоне!!!

```
print('x = 3 y = 1 z = 18')
print('x = 1 y = 4 z = 17')
```

Comment: И ещё одно решение (1,4,17). И легко доказывается, что иных решений нет.

Answer (score 2):

решение перебором:

```
for i0 in range(23):
    for i1 in range(23):
        for i2 in range(23):
            if i0 + i1 + i2 == 22:
                if i0 * 2 + i1 * 3 + i2 * 5 == 99:
                    print(i0, i1, i2)
            elif i0 + i1 + i2 > 22:break
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Danis, да вы лютый зверь - O(n^3), когда на самом деле это задача с O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

К ответу @Danis, можно немного поизвращаться с питоном:

сложность O(n^2)

```
for x in range(23):
    for y in range(23 - x):
        z = 22 - x - y
        if x * 2 + y * 3 + z * 5 == 99:
            print(x, y, z)
```

Можно сделать чуть-чуть побыстрее, чтобы не вычислять z когда не надо:

```
for x in range(23):
    for y in range(23 - x):
        if x * 3 + y * 2 == 11:
            z = 22 - x - y
            print(x, y, z)
```